# Why use "db.*" in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am working on a project using Flask and SqlAlchemy. Me and my colleagues found two ways to define a table. Both work, but what is the different?

Possibility I

```
base = declarative_base()

class Story(base):
        __tablename__ = 'stories'
        user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
        email = Column(String(100), unique=True)
        password = Column(String(100), unique=True)
```

Possibility II

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Story(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'stories'
        user_id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
        email = db.Column(String(100), unique=True)
        password = db.Column(String(100), unique=True)
```

We want to choose one option, but which one?
It is obvious that both classes inherit from a different parent class, but for what are these two possibilities used for?

Comment: use default base and using custom base and DRY each time

Answer (score 2):

Possibility 1 is [raw SQLAlchemy declarative mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping).

Possibility 2 is [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#define-models).

Both map a class to SQL table (or something more exotic in SQL) in a declarative style, i.e. the class is mapped to an automatically generated table.

Choosing which one to use however is a matter of opinion.

I'll say that using Flask-SQLAlchemy is obviously locking the application to Flask, but that's basically a non-problem since switching frameworks is very uncommon.

**NB.** `__tablename__` is optional with Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I agree with this answer. For addition, in agile architecture no. 1 is better. In terms of agility, dependency, flexibility and performance (flask-sqlalchemy somehow make it worst). But if you're a beginner, flask-sqlalchemy provide you some features to easily manage your queries.